Connect to RAC Oracle with multiple IPs from Java Spring
Since now I connect to a single Oracle instance.
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:1521/your_service_name
spring.datasource.username=your_username
spring.datasource.password=your_password
...

Now I have to configure to point to Oracle RAC with multiple IPs, I'm not able to test it now, will something like this work?
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaa.bbb.ccc.dd1)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaa.bbb.ccc.dd2)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaa.bbb.ccc.dd3)(PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=aaa.bbb.ccc.dd4)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=your_service_name)))
spring.datasource.username=your_username
spring.datasource.password=your_password
...


If you are trying to connect Oracle RAC database, you can simply use the SCAN IPs. With that way you don't need to write or delete all of the IPs when the situation becomes new nodes added or removed on Oracle RAC databases.
Generally there is a specific domain address for the SCAN IPs and when you use that domain address while connecting, it automatically resolves the SCAN IPs, and with that way the requests will be redirected to the available nodes. It also helps to load-balance on servers.
If you want to get generic information you can check the documentation: About the SCAN
